# Does the equals method work for Activity objects in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, equals

I looked in the Android source code and neither `Activity` nor any of its ancestor classes `ContextThemeWrapper`, `ContextWrapper` or `Context` override the `equals` method. Can `equals` be safely used to compare `Activity` objects?

---

[Reason I want to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): I have a notification queue that needs to be managed by the currently active activity. The activity will start managing it in its `onStart` and stop in its `onStop`. The problem is that in practice I have found when switching activities the new activity `onStart` can be called before the old activity `onStop`, and only one activity can be managing the notification queue at once. So I want to store a variable like "currentActivity" which activities can compare themselves to, to determine if some other activity `onStart` has already been called and therefore they don't need to take any action `onStop`.

Comment: why do you need an entire activity reference for this, why wouldn't a type check be sufficient ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody because you can transition between two activities of the same type. especially if they were in the back stack

Comment: try registering an activity callback on application class using `application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks`. it will notify you whenever an activity starts and stops

Comment: @mohsensameti that wouldn't remove the need to compare activities. I'd still need to check in `onActivityStopped` whether some other activity had already started. it just moves the logic from a base class to the callback, which is maybe a nice thing to do, but doesn't actually solve my problem

Comment: You should just a string variable and save activity::class.canonicalName and check that. unless you instantiate more than one of the same activity.

Comment: @mohsensameti as per my above response to a_local_nobody it can happen that there is more than one of the same activity class